# What is the use of rvalue reference member variables

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I was wondering if there is a point in having a rvalue reference variable (not as a function parameter)? I understand the use of rvalue reference when it is used as a function variable as then it is possible to avoid unnecessary allocations etc. But is there a use case rvalue reference variables that are not function parameters? Initially I thought that with such variables we could capture data that was passed in as rvalue for use later, but it seems that if we have a rvalue reference variable, then we can already take its address and therefore it can not be rvalue reference anymore.

I tried the following code and it ( unsurprisingly ) does not compile. So why would I ever want to have a rvalue reference variable?

```cc
void test(int&& a) {}

int&& a(22);
test(a);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It compiles if you `std::move(a)`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `a` here is the name of a rvalue reference. `a` itself is a lvalue (you can take its address) of type rvalue reference (yes, a bit confusing). So whenever you pass your `a` to `test(a)`, you pass a lvalue. Think about lvalues as any object that has a name, or of which you can latter take its address. And you cannot bind a lvalue to a rvalue reference, hence the compile error

> error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'

You need to pass `std::move(a)`. In this case, you cast away the lvalue-ness of `a`.

Note that inside your function `a` is also a lvalue (again, you can perform lvalue operations on it, like taking its address etc). You need a cast (`std::move`) anytime you want to use it as a rvalue. For example, say you have an object `Bar` with a member variable `Foo member;`, and you want to move into it via a member function `f`:

```
void Bar::f(Foo&& param)
{
    member = std::move(param); // need std::move here to move param into member
}

// invoked it as
bar.f(std::move(some_foo)); // move some_foo into param
```

If you don't cast `param` to a rvalue reference with `std::move`, then you don't move `param` into `member`, you just copy it (if `param` is copy-able, otherwise you get a compile-time error), since `param` itself is a lvalue. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Ok, so does this mean, that I actually do capture some rvalue reference with my a variable 'a'- the type of int&& indicates that, but to use it as an actual rvalue reference I then have to do some extra work by manually cast'ing away the lvalue-ness, which is safe, because I already know it is rvalue reference just stored in lvalue variable?

Comment: @bim_bam yes, exactly. And the "work" is just on the programmer's side, the compiler performs the cast with zero overhead.

Comment: @bim_bam I have to say that I don't know any good example of usage of a rvalue reference outside the parameter of a function, although probably someone can come up with an example.

Comment: ' And you cannot bind a lvalue to a rvalue reference' is the short answer of the question

Comment: It's clearer when you stop thinking of objects as being lvalues or rvalues; it's the _expressions_ that have value categories, not the things they name (or don't name).

Comment: if somebody could post another answer, it will be welcome since this one didn't seem to provide a clear example of rvalue reference variables that are not function parameters